Is there any way to build an sftpSupplier splitter (batch producer) with Spring Cloud Stream and RabbitMQ binder?
I'm trying to implement a Spring Cloud Stream application to:

read a gzipped file from an SFTP server
unzip it and get two fixed-length text files (a "layout" file and a "data" file with multiple records)
interpret the data file using the layout file and transform all that into JSON documents
send each document to RabbitMQ as a separate message

I've tried some different approaches, but I must be misunderstanding some things.
I've tried to model this case with a simple application, which works perfectly (generated with Spring Initializr and those relevant changes):
pom.xml
  <properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    <spring-function.version>5.0.1</spring-function.version>
  </properties>
  <!-- ... -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

Java code
@Configuration
public class CloudFunctionConfiguration {

  private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

  public CloudFunctionConfiguration(final StreamBridge streamBridge) {
    this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
  }

  @Bean
  Supplier<String> source() {
    return () -> "a,1,b,2,3,c";
  }

  @Bean
  Consumer<String> splitter() {
    return string -> {
      Arrays.asList(string.split(",")).forEach(s -> {
        final var message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload("{\"attribute\": \"".concat(s).concat("\"}"))
            .setHeader("some-header", "some-content")
            .build();
        streamBridge.send("output", message);
      });
    };
  }
}

application.properties
spring.application.name=sftp-demo
logging.level.root=DEBUG
logging.file.name=app.log
spring.cloud.function.definition=source|splitter
spring.cloud.stream.output-bindings=output
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.required-groups=app
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=ex.docs
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.source|splitter-out-0.producer.declareExchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.source|splitter-out-0.consumer.declareExchange=false
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=admin
spring.rabbitmq.password=admin

This works as expected; all messages are published each and every time the polled supplier is invoked.
But things stop working when I change that simple String supplier for the SFTP supplier function.
I've generated a sample GZipped file with three records, and then I made these changes:
pom.xml (added)
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.fn</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-sftp-supplier</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-function.version}</version><!-- 5.0.1 -->
    </dependency>

Java code (new version)
@Configuration
public class CloudFunctionConfiguration {

  protected static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudFunctionConfiguration.class);

  private final GzipMessageParser parser;
  private final StreamBridge streamBridge;

  public CloudFunctionConfiguration(
      final GzipMessageParser parser,
      final StreamBridge streamBridge) {
    this.parser = parser;
    this.streamBridge = streamBridge;
  }

  @Bean
  Consumer<Message<byte[]>> messageParser() {
    return gzipFile -> {
      parser.parse(gzipFile).forEach(message -> {
        LOGGER.info("SENDING MESSAGE {}", message);
        streamBridge.send("output", message);
      });
    };
  }

}

application.properties (changes) [edit: fixed a copy/paste mistake]
# changed
spring.cloud.function.definition=sftpSupplier|messageParser
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.sftpSupplier|messageParser-out-0.producer.declareExchange=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.sftpSupplier|messageParser-out-0.consumer.declareExchange=false
# added
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
file.consumer.mode=contents
sftp.supplier.delay-when-empty=10s
sftp.supplier.filename-regex=^some-prefix.*?GZ$
sftp.supplier.remote-dir=upload
sftp.supplier.stream=true
sftp.supplier.factory.host=localhost
sftp.supplier.factory.port=2222
sftp.supplier.factory.username=sftpuser
sftp.supplier.factory.password=sftppwd
sftp.supplier.factory.private-key=file:///opt/keys/ssh_host_rsa_key
sftp.supplier.factory.allow-unknown-keys=true

It's actually a little more complicated than that (I've configured a database and a metadata store), but I'll omit those extra configurations (for they seem to work fine).
When I run this app, all messages are sent to RabbitMQ, but I get some errors. This is what's in the log.

There is a message conversion (the whole compressed file gets converted pretty much to itself; I guess Spring Cloud Stream does this when the internal funcion pipeline passes the file from the sftpSupplier to the messageParser function)

(...) DEBUG 781757 --- [sftp-demo] [boundedElastic-1] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Converted Message: GenericMessage [payload=byte[528], headers={file_remoteHostPort=localhost:2222, file_remoteFileInfo={"directory":false,"filename":"some-prefix_doc-files.GZ","link":false,"modified":1733178662000,"permissions":"rw-r--r--","remoteDirectory":"upload","size":528}, file_remoteDirectory=upload, id=8b2b9553-cb47-fdd3-111f-6c4d39af4593, contentType=application/octet-stream, closeableResource=org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession@6b5b5c4b, file_remoteFile=some-prefix_doc-files.GZ, timestamp=1733261637557}] to: GenericMessage [payload=byte[528], headers={file_remoteHostPort=localhost:2222, file_remoteFileInfo={"directory":false,"filename":"some-prefix_doc-files.GZ","link":false,"modified":1733178662000,"permissions":"rw-r--r--","remoteDirectory":"upload","size":528}, file_remoteDirectory=upload, id=8b2b9553-cb47-fdd3-111f-6c4d39af4593, contentType=application/octet-stream, closeableResource=org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession@6b5b5c4b, file_remoteFile=some-prefix_doc-files.GZ, timestamp=1733261637557}]


I see that LOGGER.info("SENDING MESSAGE {}", message); entry, then a preSend hook log, a Publishing message (...) log and a postSend hook log.

All looks nice, but then I see this:


(...) DEBUG 781757 --- [sftp-demo] [scheduling-1] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Invoking function sftpSupplier|messageParser
(...) DEBUG 781757 --- [sftp-demo] [scheduling-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Poll resulted in Message: GenericMessage [payload=MonoMap, headers={id=e531d10a-8edc-88fd-fe07-3bba0b950a48, timestamp=1733261637927}]
(...)
(...) DEBUG 823084 --- [sftp-demo] [scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler' for component '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger' received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@4841e6], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=MonoMap, headers={id=c5903f2f-f4a7-1ca5-18e0-b76cb2f98fa6, timestamp=1733263993106}], headers={id=cb9ce0d7-bac6-0ba2-6e0e-7ac40ad989a1, timestamp=1733263993106}] for original GenericMessage [payload=MonoMap, headers={id=364cff1e-6120-f005-ee63-a34865009323, timestamp=1733263993106}]
(...) ERROR 823084 --- [sftp-demo] [scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@4841e6], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=MonoMap, headers={id=c5903f2f-f4a7-1ca5-18e0-b76cb2f98fa6, timestamp=1733263993106}]
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SimpleMessageConverter only supports String, byte[] and Serializable payloads, received: reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap

That is, Spring Cloud Stream is polling the function definition and automatically binding it to the RabbitMQ Binder. Since the poll results in a message with a Mono payload (I don't know why), the binder tries to convert the message and send it - and then it fails.
Curiously, my first working example does this polling as well, but this is the result:
DEBUG 759414 --- [demo] [scheduling-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'

And that's why it works, I think.
Then I've also tried the functional batch producer approach (by creating a Function<Message<String>, List<Message<String>>>), but I couldn't get the application to send the messages individually; RabbitMQ just gets one message with the serialized List.
It looks like I shouldn't be doing this thing this way, but by reading the docs I got the impression I could (and should?) compose functions (Spring Cloud Functions with my own) to easily build integration applications.
So how could I build such an application? Should I just do it with Spring Integration, or is there something I can do in code or configuration?

There are so many moving parts, therefore hard to judge what is wrong. I see your spring.cloud.function.definition=sftpSupplier|messageParser|messageSplitter, but there is no messageSplitter in your code. Plus messageParser is not a function to be specified in the middle of definition. I also think that your whole composite Runnable is not supposed to be bound at all, since you produce into Rabbit using StreamBridge. You need to think if binder is needed here at all, since there is a n out-of-the-box rabbitConsumer function implementation.

I also wonder if the UnZipTransformer from Spring Integration can do the stuff for you. I'll to write some sample application with your requirements, although I'm not sure that I can come up with some GZIP formant for your content. The sftp.supplier.stream=true mean that sftpSupplier would produce Flux<Message<InputStream>>, not byte[]. Perhaps Spring Cloud Function does that trick to convert it back to byte[] when those functions are composed. I'll see that when develop the mentioned sample. No promises when it will be ready or that it will be exactly as you model now.

Thank you very much, @ArtemBilan.
That function definition was definitely a typo (I was changing lots of things to experiment, and should have double-checked all that copy and paste). It was supposed to be just sftpSupplier|messageParser.
Since I'm just a beginner in Spring Cloud, I suspected I had done something odd.
I'll try those approaches (with a rabbitConsumer function and no binder, and then with the UnzipTransformer as an extra step), and I'll check back if I can make this work.
Thanks again!

So, here is some kind of answer to your straggle: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-functions-catalog/pull/108.
Honestly, even I had some obstacles to figure out how to make everything working together.
With that sample, you can replace simple fileSupplier to your sftpSupplier requirements and so on.
I didn't try with StreamBridge, but that is possible anyway, although it would disconnect the purpose of functions composition a bit.

Yes, the documentation is very clear about the purpose of StreamBridge, which is to bridge foreign data sources with Spring Cloud Stream's functional mechanism — but I was using sftpSupplier, and therefore that wasn't the case; I knew I wasn't on the right track here. Thank you very much for the awesome support.
